# Prove for chronological future of open subset of a spacetime $(M, g)$

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, time

I'm currently reading $\textit{Semi-Riemannian Geometry}$ of B. O' Neill and after giving the definition of chronological (causal) future (past), he says that:

Given a spacetime $(M, g)$ and a open subset of it $(U, g\lvert_U)$, prove that for an open subset $A\subset U$, its chronological future $I^+(A, U)$ satifies:
$$I^+(A, U) \subseteq I^+(A)\cap U$$
where $I^+(A)$ is the set of points of $M$ connected with $A$ with timelike future oriented curves. $I^+(A, U)$ is the set of points of $U$ connected with $A$ with timelike future oriented curves.

He doesn't give any proof for that and I'm struggling to find one. Any help? Do you know any text where this is proven?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $p\in I^{+}(A,U)$. By definition of $I^{+}(A,U)$, $p\in U$. We know that $U\subset M$ so, by definition of $I^{+}(A)$, we have that $I^{+}(A,U)\subseteq I^{+}(A)$. This proves what you want.